# Create column in dataframe that divides number by days in a month

Tags: python, pandas, date, divide

I have a Panda's DataFrame with a column of months and a column that gives a total for each month. What I need to do is divide the total for each month by the number of days in that month and put it in a new column.

So something like this

```
Month          Total        Daily Total
Nov. 2019      45345
Dec. 2019      87493
Jan. 2020      45765
Feb. 2020      38756
```

How do I do this? How do I know how many days are in a given month using Python? Thanks

Comment: Please display your data in a understandable way

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.dt.daysinmonth](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.daysinmonth.html)

```py
df['Daily Total'] = df['Total'] / pd.to_datetime(df['Month']).dt.daysinmonth
```

```
print(df)

       Month  Total  Daily Total
0  Nov. 2019  45345  1511.500000
1  Dec. 2019  87493  2822.354839
2  Jan. 2020  45765  1476.290323
3  Feb. 2020  38756  1336.413793
```